# Creating decision variables with conditions in pyomo

Tags: pyomo

I want to create decision variables only if they satisfy certain conditions about their index. Say I have a decision variable inventory(t,d) on index t and d. I want to create inventory only if the d value is lower than or equal to t value. It should create inventory(5,4) but not inventory(3,4). I dont want to declare inventory(3,4)=0 because I have a lot of that kind of decision variables and it will take memory to handle them.